# How to separate regex in javascript Hours format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some problem to define hours time, i want to separate hours time to 3 time type morning, evening, and night.
if time start from 00:00 to 10:00 the type time is morning,
if time start from 10:01 to 18:00 the type time is evening,
if time start from 18:01 to 23:59 the type time is night,
i have code jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){

        var hrs=$('#hours').val();
        var nm=$('#scedule').val();

        var patt = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
            var patts = patt.test(hrs);

        //morning   =   00:00 - 10:00
        var morn = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$");
            var morning = morn.test(hrs);

        //evening   =   10:01 - 18:00
        var even = new RegExp("^(1[0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$");
            var evening = even.test(hrs);

        //night =   18:01 - 00:00
        var nig = new RegExp("^(1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
            var night = nig.test(hrs);

        if ( patts == morning ) {
            alert('This is Morning');
        } else if (patts == evening){
            alert('This is Evening');
        } else if (patts == night){
            alert('This is night');
        } else {
            alert('Format is wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my form HTML :

```
    Scedule : <input type="text" id="scedule"><br>
    Time : <input type="text" id="hours"><br>   
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"><br>
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that?  Can you simply use `if (hrs <= "10:00")`, `if (hrs > "10:00" && hrs <= "18:00")`, `if (hrs > "18:00")` ?

Comment: @wdosanjos it's because the lt and gt operators don't work too well on numerical strings. `"9:00" > "10:00"` would be true for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Got it.  Probably is easier to normalize the string `if (hrs.length < 5) hrs = '0' + hrs` prior to testing, then using regex.

Comment: wow i don't thin its work but, i was try it and worth.,,, thank you bro

Comment: Btw. your morning regex includes `1[0-9]` which matches 10 - 19 and your evening regex matches `10:00`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex here, just use `Date`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){

        var hrs=$('#hours').val();
        if(hrs.length != 5 || hrs.indexOf(':') < 0)
        {
            alert("Wrong Fromat")
            return;
        }

        var date = new Date();
        date.setHours(hrs.split(":")[0]);
        date.setMinutes(hrs.split(":")[1]);
        console.log(date)
      
       

        if ( date.getHours() < 10) {
            console.log('This is Morning');
        } else if (date.getHours() > 18 && date.getMinutes > 0){
           console.log('This is night');
        } else{
           console.log('This is Evening');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Time : <input type="text" id="hours"><br>   
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"><br>
```